# How to raise the screen when the keyboard is activated in flutter

Tags: flutter

When the keyboard is activated, I want to raise the entire screen as much as the keyboard is raised. And if it is deactivated again, it should return to its original state.

I tried

- resizeToAvoidBottomInset of scaffold
- SingleChildScrollView + reverse: true (problem with this method is that the list appears backwards)

ex)

```
Scaffold( 
... 
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, 
body: CustomRefreshIndicator( 
child: ListView( 
...
```

Comment: What’s wrong with resizeToAvoidBottomInset?

Comment: Scaffold(
...
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
body: 
CustomRefreshIndicator(
    child: ListView(
...




I'm using it like the code above

However, the keyboard does not work even when raised.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` in Padding should do the trick

```
Padding(padding:MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets, child: //Your Widget);
```

Comment: So where should I put the text field?

Comment: In child parameter. Replace `//Your Widget` with your `Text("Hello")`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your entire screen or the portion you want to be raised, with the viewInset's bottom padding. you can get it's value from `MediaQuery.viewPaddingOf(context).bottom`

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.viewPaddingOf(context).bottom,
      ),
      child: ...,
    ),
  ),
);
```

---

With this, I wrapped the body of the scaffold, because I don't want to raise the entire scaffold, just it's contents, and only to the `bottom`, so that it only lifts the screen's bottom, you can go ahead and use other values for the other parts of the padding, like `left`, `top`, `right`

Comment: Then where should I put the floating textfield?

Comment: @inho put it in your ListView, the child ends with ... because you alredy had a ListView that was wrapped with a CustomRefreshIndicator there, so I'm saying leave the rest of your UI the same, the only part that needs to change is the body's padding